# Why does my lighting look like a glowing dot?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I followed a Ducky3d easy environment tutorial and his lighting looked way better than mine. I followed his tutorial step by step and his lighting looked so much brighter and his lighting WATT was pretty low. I had to turn my lighting up to over 2000W while he was using around 50W or 60W. Even his default WATT was 10W and mines is at 1000W. I looked at some of his other tutorials and even other videos but all of their lighting was super good. Please someone help. I've been searching for an answer for days[image: this is Ducky3d tutorial][This is Ducky3D tutorial screenshot from the video. The one below is mine. He was using eevee and so was I. My computer is too slow for cycles.][image: These are my settings on the right]

[image: My final rendered image]

Comment: There might be other reasons but from what I see, his light color is white and yours orange, and most of all your Radius is much higher, it will soften the shadows but it will decrease the brightness a lot, maybe these two things explain?

Comment: I agree with moonboots. Firstly, the white light is brighter than orange because all RGB channels have 100% brightness, while your orange is 100% red, 15% green and only 2% blue. Also the size: 1000 W with a radius of 10 m is darker than 1000 W with 0.1 m.
Secondly, another thing is the light radius given in relation to the tunnel radius. For example, the radius in the tutorial is 0.25 m and let's say the tunnel radius is 5 m, than all light is inside and brightens the walls. Your light radius is 12 m, which means the light extends the tunnel by 7 m so some of the light is on the outside.