# Why is their weird noise in my render lighing and why does my lighitng still look off?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I followed the tutorial [*here*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_DJB70hFyU&t=346s) by Ducky3D, and it turned out I needed to scale down my scene a lot as light keeps flickering every time I move around my scene and the final result still doesn't look that good.

Also when I rendered the image, there was weird noise around my scene because of my lighting.

[image: I had to scale down the image a little bit]

Comment: Would you mind, sharing some pictures of your render? 

Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201655/why-does-my-lighting-look-like-a-glowing-dot

Comment: What's the "Ducky3D environment"? Can you please share a link?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_DJB70hFyU&t=346s     Here is the one I used to make the environment.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the default shadow settings for Eevee.  Try setting the cube size higher in this menu.

[image]